# Subtracting all the values inside an array from the first item

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math

So i have this array of objects that looks like this:

```
let budgetData = [{title: "Monthly Income", amount: "2500"}, {title: 
"rent", amount: "1000"},{title: "car", amount: "200"};
```

I am trying to some math like this:

2500 - 1000 - 200 = whatever this comes out too. You can continue to add amounts to this array until you have added your monthly expenses.

When you run this the first time with only two values the amount is what you would expect (ie. 2 - 1 = 1).

However add anymore than two amounts to the array it only subtracts whatever the last value is from the first value.(ie. 5 - 2 - 1 = 4).

```
let amount = [];

for (let i = 1; i < budgetData.length; i++){ amount = 
budgetData[0].amount - budgetData[i].amount;


Console.log(amount) === 2300
```

So this code with the above info the answer comes out to: 2300 when I am expecting it to say 1300.

Where am I going wrong with this, also, is there some built in math function that will do what I am trying to do?

Comment: you don't keep a running total.

Comment: In other words you keep overwriting `amount` in each iteration of loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time through the loop you're throwing away what you calculated before, and overwriting `amount` with a new calculation. So what you end up at the very end is just subtracting the very last number from the first number.

Instead, you need to keep a running tally. Something like this:

```js
let budgetData = [
  {title: "Monthly Income", amount: "2500"}, 
  {title: "rent", amount: "1000"},
  {title: "car", amount: "200"}
];

let amount = budgetData[0].amount;

for (let i = 1; i < budgetData.length; i++){ 
   amount = amount - budgetData[i].amount;
}

console.log(amount);
```

Comment: Hmm only issue is the budgetData array is nothing until a user inputs something so I get the "amount is undefined" error.

Comment: Yes, you would only want to run this code when you have data. If you need to check for the possibility that you don't have data, you can wrap it all in an `if (!budgetData || budgetData.length === 0)`

Comment: Some weird behavior but it works now. With no IF statement it goes equals to a negative number add the IF statement and it subtracts normally with no undefined error. This works just as intended. I always seem to forget about keep track of the running total when trying to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could *reduce* the array:

```
const total = budgetData.reduce((previous, current) => (previous.amount || previous) - current.amount);
```

If your budget objects implement a *valueOf* method, like this:

```
 class Budget {
  constructor(settings){
     Object.assign(this, settings);
  }
  valueOf(){ return this.amount;}
}

budgetData = budgetData.map(el => new Budget(el));
```

It gets even more beautiful:

```
const total = budgetData.reduce((a,b) => a-b);
```

Comment: Same situation, the array is initialized with nothing until user input is taken.